# php/mysql advanced search page

Tags: php, sql

I faced a problem in developing advanced search code using php as an input and output, sql to select and filter data ..

php code:

```
<form action="index.php?Type=Advance" method="post">
      <input type="text"   name="name">
                <input type="text"   name="sponsor">

    <select size="1" name="gender" id="">
    <option value="male">male</option>
    <option value="female">female</femal>
</select>
                       <select size="1" name="address" id="">
    <option value="x">x</option>
    <option value="y">y</option>
    <option value="z">z</option>
       </select>
             <input type="submit">
  </form>
```

Then i declare the variables

public function AdvanceSearch($name,$sponsor,$gender,$address)
{

```
$cheack = "";
if(isset($name)&&$name != ""){
    $cheack.="  name =  '$name' ";
}
if(isset($sponsor)&&$sponsor != ""){
    $cheack.=" AND sponsor =  '$sponsor' ";
}
if(isset($gender)&&$gender != ""){
    $cheack.=" AND gender =  '$gender' ";
}
if(isset($address) &&$address != "" ){
    $cheack.=" AND workplace =  '$address' ";
}
   $DB = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE 1 =  1 ".$cheack);
   echo "SELECT * FROM user WHERE ".$WHQ;
   exit();
```

actually it works, however if i didn't insert the name ... the sql statement will be like this

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE AND sponsor = 'www' 
    AND gender = 'male'
```

what if i want to search on the table but without inserting the name .. how can i let the sql statement works if i didn't inset the name.

Comment: Not sure I understand... it looks like it would work if you didnt declare name as $cheack would instead consist of sponsor/gender/address... what is not working? Error messages? Also i'm not sure why you have `WHERE 1 = 1` in your statement at all.

Comment: Make sure to properly escape the query string when not using parameters with `mysql_real_escape_string()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A typical solution to this is always adding a true condition first, such as `1=1`. The query without any extra conditions then becomes

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 1=1
```

and when you add any `AND` conditions you can just add them to the end, with no special case for the first or last condition:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 1=1 AND sponsor = 'www' AND gender = 'male'
```

Note that if you used OR instead of AND the first condition should be false, like `0=1`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a flag variable like :

```
$cheack = "";
$flag = False;

if(isset($name)&&$name != ""){
 $cheack.="  name =  '$name' ";
 $flag =True;
}

if(isset($sponsor)&&$sponsor != ""){
 if($flag){
  $cheack.="AND ";
 }
 $cheack.="sponsor =  '$sponsor' ";
}

if(isset($gender)&&$gender != ""){
 if($flag){
  $cheack.="AND ";
 }
 $cheack.="gender =  '$gender' ";
}

if(isset($address) &&$address != "" ){
 if($flag){
  $cheack.="AND ";
 }
 $cheack.="workplace =  '$address' ";
}
```